# WSO2 XACML REST API

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I try to use REST API to evaluate XACML requests as in the below documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+REST+APIs+via+XACML+to+Manage+Entitlement

But I get `500 Internal server error` and in the XACML logs, I see

> "No operation matching request path
>   "/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp" is found, Relative Path:
>   /pdp, HTTP  Method: POST, ContentType:
>   application/xml,application/xml, Accept: application/xml,."

#### XACML request

```xml
<Request
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">customer1</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">POST</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/team</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Could somebody help to identify the issue ?

Regards,
Albie Morken

Comment: Can you paste your request? It got mangled up

Comment: Formatted the request

Answer (score 0):

I validate your XACML request using the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point. It is correct.

[image]

Given the error you receive is

> "No operation matching request path
>   "/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp" is found, Relative Path:
>   /pdp, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/xml,application/xml,
>   Accept: application/xml,."

I am suspecting the issue is the URI / path you are using. You need to check how the REST PDP is exposed. For instance, inside the Axiomatics Policy Server, the PDP is exposed as https://host:port/asm-pdp/authorize. The [REST Profile of XACML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-rest/v1.0/xacml-rest-v1.0.html) states how to retrieve the endpoint.

Comment: The problem was with the jersey client since it didn't accept the headers which I passed. Instead, I had to use thier APIs to set the contentType as "application/xml"

Comment: ContentType application/xml is not a valid content type for a XACML JSON request / response.